# Let $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$ be a sequence of disjoint elementary sets. If $A = \cup A_i$ is elementary, then $m'(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty m'(A_i)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Definition 1**. Let the set

$$S := \{S \subset \mathbb{R}^2 ;  R = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 ; a \leq x \leq b \ \text{and}  \ c \leq y \leq d \}\}.$$

**Definition 2.** We define that $m(\emptyset) = 0$ and $m(R) = (d - c)(b - a)$, for every $R \in  S \ne \emptyset$.

**Definition 3.** We say that a subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is elementary if the set is a finite union of disjoint elements of $S$.

**Definition 4.** Let $A = \cup_{i = 1}^n S_i$ be a elementary set. Then $m'(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^n m(S_i)$.

I'm studying for a summer of Measure Theory and I came across this Theorem:

**Let $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$ be a sequence of disjoint elementary sets. If $A = \cup A_i$ is elementary, then $m'(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^\infty m'(A_i)$**

My proof:

1. $m'(A) \geq \sum_{i = 1}^\infty m'(A_i)$.

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, take

$$B_n = A - \cup_{i = 1}^n A_n.$$

Then $B_n$ is elementary and $A = B_n \cup A_1 \cup ... \cup A_n$. Note that

$$m'(A) = m'(B_n) + \sum_{i = 1}^n m'(A_i) \geq \sum_{i = 1}^n m'(A_i), $$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore

$$m'(A) \geq \sum_{i = 1}^\infty m'(A_i).$$

**My doubt is: How do I prove the opposite?**

The professor suggested that we prove the following Lemma:

**Lemma. Let $A, A_1, A_2, ..., A_n, ...$ be a elementary sets such that $A \subseteq \cup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i$. Then $m'(A) \leq \sum_{i = 1}^\infty m'(A_i).$**

I would be grateful if you could help me prove the opposite inequality with any suggestions or indicating where I can find this proof. Thanks.

Comment: Please, define $m'$ and "elementary sets"

Comment: What is m' in this context?

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku i defined

Comment: try putting all left and right edges in one list "horizontal", and all top and bottom edges in one list "vertical" (by edge i mean the real number representing the coordinate at which the edge lies). now split all rectangles in your elementary sets with all lines from both lists. this gives you the proof, but in case when your rectangles are semi-open ("clopen") in both axes. by your definition, every elementary set has a unique representation as a finite union of closed rectangles, so the summation formula follows trivially. clopen rectangles are more interesting and useful.

Comment: The definition of $S$ uses $S$, so you should probably fix it. Did you want to say that elementary sets are unions of rectangles?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Yes, sir!